# What can I change with gtkrc-2.0?

Tags: themes, gtk, nautilus-elementary, colors

We can change breadcrumbs and the sidepane color, but what else can be edited with `gtkrc-2.0`?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the appearance of virtually all [widgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUI_widget), the `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file overrides the settings of whatever Gtk theme you are using. For this reason, it usually is best to modify the theme directly *(They are located in `~/.themes/` and `/usr/share/themes/`)* or else whenever you change your Gtk theme *(System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Themes -> Customize... -> Controls)* it will be overridden by `~/.gtkrc-2.0`.

For more information on Gtk theming, check out the [Gtk Theming Tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes).